# Simple local/offline photo gallery

Tags: windows, photography, gallery

I have a big directory with photographs. There are some subdirectories, and some of those contain a *lot* of photos. For my own needs I use whatever sophisticated software I need, but there are other family members who are not technophile and just want to occasionally view photographs.

I am looking for an application that lets them do that, and nothing else. No processing, no folders, no sorting, no filters, no labels, no "stars", no printing services, no "photo management", no uploading, no metadata, nothing. Just viewing the photographs like you would have 50 years ago with a dia projector or when opening a real-world photo book.

It is OK if the application *has* more features but if I can configure them away so they are not intruding.

Obviously, being intuitive would be a huge bonus, i.e., they should have no trouble actually browsing through the photos in a sensible way; the directory structure should be readily visible, the UX should be good. It would be nice if they would not need to browse to the photo directory everytime they start; and if they could be protected from accidentally browsing "away" and getting lost somewhere.